# Accessing Hive Variables in a Java Program opening a JDBC connection to HiveServer2

Tags: java, variables, jdbc, hive, hiveql

I need to know is there a way to set and use hive variables in Java.

I know the Hive CLI we can do something like:

```
hive>set hiveconf:tablename=sample_07;

hive>select * from ${hiveconf:tablename};
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in java?

Comment: You mean Java UDF or what?

Comment: Would prefer to be able to do this without writing a UDF, a UDF based solution would also help.

Comment: what do you mean by `use hive variables in Java` in your question?

Comment: For example, I need to be able to define a variable in the hiveconf namespace and use it in my hive queries. I should be able to do this set hiveconf:tablename=sample_07 and then use ${hiveconf:tablename} in a select query.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by *"in java"*. Since you refer to the CLI syntax, do you mean "in a java program opening a JDBC connection to HiveServer2"?

Comment: Sorry if the way I have framed the question is confusing. You are right, that's exactly what I am looking for.